# In launcher, disable the music suggestion section

Tags: launcher

Everytime I want to launch an office program, I begin typing "of" in the launcher, and... pictures of lightly-clothed ladies show up.

Not the end of the world, but because I do this a lot in front of customers and bosses, it is often embarrassing.

I have already [disabled Zeitgeist and "recently used"](https://askubuntu.com/a/149799/4066).
Banshee does not have any Zeitgeist item in `Edit > Preferences > Extensions`.

Is there a way to disable this "Music" section in the launcher suggestions?
Or maybe I just must stop playing dance music via Banshee...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `unity-lens-music` package.