# 'zeitgeist-fts' always using a lot of memory!

Tags: ram, memory-usage, zeitgeist

**What is `zeitgeist-fts`?!**
It's always in the 3 top positions of memory usage (competing with `Firefox` and `Compiz`) . After a fresh boot it uses about 30 MB, but after some hours or a day, **it goes above 300 MB** and stays there !

The file of this process is located at `/usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts`. I don't know what this thing does, but if it doesn't break any functionality, I would be really happy to remove it, because memory capacity is very precious to me.

**Edit:** I'm using Unity desktop on Ubuntu-12.04.2 LTS.

Comment: 14.04 fresh install.  After two days zeit... it is using 5Gb from 6Gb Ram :-)

Comment: For me it is using 2 GB out of total 4GB and moreover it is overflowing to swap :(

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### What zeitgeist is

> Zeitgeist is a service which logs the users’s activities and events, anywhere from 
>   files opened to websites visited and
>   conversations. It makes this information readily available for other
>   applications to use in form of timelines and statistics. It is able to
>   establish relationships between items based on similarity and usage
>   patterns by applying data association algorithms such as “Winepi” and
>   “A Priori”
>
> Zeitgeist is the main engine and logic behind GNOME Activity Journal which is 
>   currently seen to become one of the main means of
>   viewing and managing activities in GNOME version 3.0

[Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_%28framework%29)

### How to quick-fix it

As zeitgeist is a journal, it'll grow bigger day after day, leading to ram consummation problem.

The easiest way to solve this is to make some clean by removing the current journal to let a new one take its place. It's not dangerous and can be done with a single command-line :

`rm -r ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/`

Or with your your file browser (`ctrl` + `h` to display `.`hidden file) :

in your Home folder (~/) **> `.local` > `share`**, and remove **`zeitgeist`**

Your Ram consummation should be back to normal after a reboot. You can stay with this solution and wait until the next zeitgeist problem (probably in some years), or try one of the following solution.

### How to disable it

(without remove it)

**Better would be to disable it instead of removing it.**

First open **startup applications and UN-tick zeitgeist** from startup automatically.

[image: description]

If you don't see zeitgeist in startup applications, open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue the following command

```
sudo sed 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' -i /etc/xdg/autostart/zeitgeist-datahub.desktop
```

**Turn off Record Activity**

Open Privacy settings and turn off Record Activity. 
[image]

Last but not least, remove the execution bits to prevent application from running.

From a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/zeitgeist-datahub
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts
```

*The `zeitgeist-fts` could be in an different location from what is specified here. If you cannot find it, issue the following commands one-by-one to locate the correct path.*

```
sudo updatedb
locate zeitgeist-fts
```

### How to remove it

**Following might be dangerous** and remove also some important packages for Dash functionality.

> Run `sudo apt-get remove zeitgeist*` in a terminal. It might remove a
>   few related packages, but so long as you don't see anything suggested
>   for removal that you don't want, you should be fine.
>
> As per comments: you will lose unity functionality (I was not sure how
>   much when I first wrote the answer) if you remove zeitgeist. So, I
>   suggest you just disable logging.
>
> If you don't need unity to function correctly, you can go ahead and
>   remove zeitgeist, and just use the classic session (from the login
>   screen).
>
> You can also blacklist everything or turn off logging [altogether](http://iloveubuntu.net/activity-log-manager-08-handy-gui-blacklisting-zeitgeists-activity-released-ppa).

[Source: AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/45549/95393)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I opted the "Disable It" option, but I only did remove it from startup and turned-off 'Record Activity'. I didn't remove the exec permissions of the files, I thought it was too much `:)` ... Let's see how it goes and I'll give feedback again ... Just to make sure: This doesn't break any functionalities of Dash or Unity? Right?!

Comment: No, if you only disable it without removing it, it doesn't break any functionalities on Dash. I did this (checked) myself before posting ;-)

Comment: The two operations I did didn't fix the problem and again 'zeitgeist-fts' went above 300 MB memory usage! ... Guess I have to remove the exec permissions of the 'zeitgeist' files!

Comment: I had a huge memory leak (700+ MB of memory after one use of Unity Dash) because of Zeitgeist and I fixed it by disabling recording activity & restart and activating it again. Without this service, working on the computer is nastier (tried it, also), I use "Recent files" very often, so I do not wish to navigate to some folder each time I open a frequently used file. In the last 2-3 days, `zeitgeist-fts` uses less than 5 MB of memory. I guess there was some error in the index file and disabling&reenabling the service fixed it. PS: I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't find the last file. It exists however  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist-fts, I guess it is this one ??

Comment: @Antonello, yes it is. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue but for IO. Just wanted to let people know this works as well for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

There are times when zeitgeist-fts starts acting up really weird. The issue is very erratic and not really easily reproducible at times.

One workaround is to delete the fts.index directory

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/fts.index/
```

then it will try to reindex it. I guess the high memory consumption is due to broken index. Deleting the index will force zeitgeist-fts to try to reindex it again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ... Although I think I will be better of just disabling zeitgeist all together.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling activity recording (as explained by @NikTh), remove zeitgeist data altogether:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/
```

This folder will be recreated on next reboot with empty data and zeitgeist process won't take so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, to disable service restart after reboot:

```
cd /usr/lib/systemd/user
sudo ln -snf /dev/null zeitgeist-fts.service
```